# Creating Registrant using gotowebinar API with jquery ajax call

Tags: ajax, json, api, jquery

I am new in using of GotoWebinar api. I am trying to create registrant with ajax request, but I am facing this error. "405 Method Not Allowed" . 
Below is the code. Can you please guide me on this?

I am using jquery.min v1.3.2 and jquery.json-2.4.min jquery files

```
var JSONObject = {
"firstName": "Tom",
"lastName": "green", 
"email": "Tom@green.com"
};

var jsonData=$.toJSON(JSONObject);  
var StrURL ="https://api.citrixonline.com/G2W/rest/organizers/323232323/webinars/1231211/registrants";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: StrURL,
    data: jsonData,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(data1) {
        alert("success = =" + data1);
    },
    error:function(s, a, c) {
       alert("error" + s + a + c);
    }
```

Comment: dude, may be this is causing error 
var StrURL = https://api.citrixonline.com/G2W/rest/organizers/323232323/webinars/1231211/registrants;
should be like 
var StrURL = 'https://api.citrixonline.com/G2W/rest/organizers/323232323/webinars/1231211/registrants';  Surround with single quotes and end by semicolon

Comment: Sorry, just missed to embed in quotes while submitting this post. But its there in my code.